# How to use VBT-1 vibration sensor? Why the measurement unit is in mm/s?

Tags: sensor, frequency, vibration, velocity

I need to use this vibration sensor for my project. I'm confused because of the measurement units. Out value of the sensor is in current 0-20mA, which corresponds to 0-25 mm/sec. Why is it being measured in velocity terms?

Please find the link to the datasheet [here](http://www.dwyer-inst.com/PDF_files/PC_VBT.pdf).

Comment: link to datasheet is where?

Comment: [Here's why velocity is important.](http://www.vibescorp.ca/learn-about/basic-understanding-of-machinery-vibration/)

Comment: Think about it this way:  If your machine is sliding across the room at a constant speed, it isn't accelerating but it will soon move far enough to pull its own plug out of the wall.

Comment: That "datasheet" is actually the mounting instructions, and doesn't mention the units.

Comment: I don't see any info on the output in that document. Where did you get the info that it produces 0-20mA for 0-25mm/sec? I've never seen any vibration sensor specified in units of velocity rather than acceleration.

Comment: @JRE Thanks for that link, that's an awesome document.

Answer (score -1):

That's just a voice coil plus rectifier plus low-pass. So it cannot measure acceleration but only velocity.

Comment: Even if you're correct about that device using a voice-coil, how would that make it a velocity sensor instead of acceleration?

Comment: Electromagnetic Induction: U=v * L * B0. I don't see *a* here but *v*.

Comment: I seriously doubt it. Most industrial sensors like this have built in signal processing/conditioning.